# Angular content projection without enclosing tag

Tags: angular

is there a way to implement content projection without enclosing tag?

Here is my component:

```
<div class="flex flex-column container">
  <div class="flex flex-column header">
    <ng-content select="[header]"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-column body">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-column footer">
    <ng-content select="[footer]"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note there are two possible slots `header` and `footer`. This is how those componentes should be used:

```
<div header>Header</div>
Body
<div footer>Footer</div>
```

How do I use this component without this `div`? I mean, I'd like to add only content because if I add `div`, it may break layout.

EDIT01:
Ok, I found a way to do it but is it a good practice?

If I change component to:

```
<div class="flex flex-column container">
  <div class="flex flex-column header">
    <ng-content select="header"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-column body">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-column footer">
    <ng-content select="footer"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

And use it as:

```
<header>Header Content</header>
Body
<footer>Footer Content</footer>
```

It does work but is there any drawbacks on this?

Comment: why can't you just create 2 different components for header and footer and add them with their tags?

Comment: Becaus it is a self container component that may be customized, I mean, I'd like to allow some placeholders in defined places.

Comment: Doesn't seem convenient. I mean I get what you want to do but the best way is using multiple components I think

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ngProjectAs` attribute on `ng-container` tag:

```
<ng-container ngProjectAs="[header]">Header</ng-container>
Body
<ng-container ngProjectAs="[footer]">Footer</ng-container>
```

More on this in [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#projecting-content-in-more-complex-environments)